# Problem with R error when using dplyr::distinct(): "no applicable method for 'distinct_' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')""

Tags: r, dplyr, distinct

Here's my example dataframe:

```
df.ex <- structure(
  list(
    id_1 = c(15796L, 15796L, 15799L, 15799L),
    id_2 = c(61350L,
             351261L, 61488L, 315736L),
    days = c(30.5, 36.4854, 30.5, 30.5)
  ),
  row.names = c(NA,-4L),
  class = "data.frame",
  .Names = c("id_1",
             "id_2", "days")
)
```

I am getting this error with `dplyr::distinct()`

```
Error in UseMethod("distinct_") : no applicable method for 'distinct_' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
```

What's confusing is that it works whenever I pass a dataframe to the function and specify the column like this: `distinct(df.ex, days)`. However, if I create a vector of the variable of interest like so: `days_vec <- df.ex$days` and pass the vector as an argument to the function like so: `distinct(days_vec)` I then get the error.

In my actual code I need to use `distinct` in a dplyr pipe like so:

```
df.ex %>% summarise(distinct_values = distinct(days))
```

And of course, this also doesn't work. Does anyone know how to overcome this error?

Many thanks,
Peter

EDIT: for my acutal problem I need to make a summary table with the  count of distinct values for `days` which would be grouped by `id_1`, it would look like this:

```
result <- tibble(
  id_1 = c(15796, 15799),
  count_distinct_values = c(2, 1)
)
```

I would have thought that the following would help, however it returns another error:

```
result <- df.ex %>% group_by(id_1) %>% summarise(count_distinct_values = count(distinct(., days)))
```

Any ideas would be very much appreciated.

Comment: The first argument to `distinct` is data.frame, when you are doing `df.ex %>% summarise(distinct_values = distinct(days))`, you are passing `days` to it which is a vector, hence the error.  What are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE accordingly to question. I think this solves your problem:

```
df.ex %>% group_by(id_1) %>% summarise(distinct_values = n_distinct(days))
```

Comment: Thanks, these work. However, i should have been more specific in my question. I need it to return a data frame. I'll edit the question to make that more clear. Thanks

Comment: If you need a data frame, remove `pull` from the second way. I edit my answer.

Comment: thanks again,  I edited my question to make it more clear what I'm looking for. basically I need a summary table using a group_by with the ID, but this is returning an error.

Comment: I edited my answer. It seems you need `n_distinct`. Is it?

Comment: Wow thanks that's exactly what I need! But it would still be good to understand why `count(distinct(., days))` doesn't return the same thing. In theory it should give the correct result!

Comment: It seems that `distinct(., days)` produces a data frame with 2 rows corresponding to the 2 distinct days, so applying `count` to it produces a tibble of 1 element with value 2. But it is not consistent with the error that `summarise` produces, so I don't know.